# C# how to get hours and minutes from decimal value

Tags: c#

Hi I have the following decimal value:

```
98.78499994
```

Right now I'm using:

```
time = TimeSpan.FromHours(Convert.ToDouble(model.TotalDuration));
```

> But I get 2 hours and 47 minutes, and I should get 98 hours and 47 minutes.

Any clue?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2znClX - seems to work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the right value. 98.78 is 4 days, 2 hours and 47 minutes.
Just check the other properties of the TimeSpan, in your case:

```
time.Minutes == 47
time.Days == 4
time.TotalHours == 98.785
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at the `TotalHours` property of `time`, not the `Hours` property.